# Safari/Chrome selection issue inside shadow dom using IOS device

Tags: reactjs, tiptap, prose-mirror

I have an issue while using tiptap on Safari/Chrome inside Shadow Dom using IOS while typing in Japanese (and other similar languages like Chinese, Korean, and Thai).

When typing using Japanese characters, the entire comment is constantly selected which can cause some problems.

**Steps to reproduce:**

On Safari IOS try to type in Japanese.
If you select a predictive text and then continue typing, it will remove all your text.
OR
When clicking the “Return” button instead of just adding a new line it will replace the current text.

I am wondering if there is some workaround here ?

here is some sendbox which you can open in your IOS device to repreduce the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/aged-platform-ssf6ks?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

some basic explantion regarding the tiptap library -
under the hood tiptap uses prosemirror .
prosemirror-state is responsible for the selection and the last version of prosemirror-state has a dependency of prosemirror-view which i saw some discussions regarding some issues in Shadow Dom.
the version of prosemirror-view that prosemirror-state use is 1.27.0 which is not the latest version of prosemirror-view.

thanks for advance for any help.

while typing using Japanese characters the word is being selected which causes some problems in different scenarios